# Break line in PowerShell to create CVS

Tags: powershell, csv

Is there any approach to break line in the same column in a CSV constructed by PowerShell? For example

```
Role     |Scope
--------------------
Role 01  |Scope 01
         |Scope 02
--------------------
Role 02  |Scope 01
         |Scope 03
```

I'm not sure if this is achievable. If not, what would be the supported format e.g. HTML?

[Updated] Below is my CSV object construct

```
class CsvObj {
   [Object] ${Role}
   [Object] ${Scope}
}

$roleList= Get-Role
$array = @()

ForEach ($role in $roleList) {
   $roleObj = [CsvObj]::new()
   $roleObj.Role = $role.Role
   $roleObj.Scope = $role.Scope
   $array += $roleObj
}
$array | Export-Csv -Path C:\file.csv
```

Each role may have more scopes and I'd like to group them properly.

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of having data that's easy to process afterwards I'd suggest you instead prepare it like this:

```
Role     Scope
----     -----
Role 01  Scope 01
Role 01  Scope 02
Role 02  Scope 01
Role 02  Scope 03
```

That way you can always just group it by doing something like

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | group Role
```

whereas the alternative for the other version would be quite a bit more complicated.

You can insert line breaks in CSV cells just fine, but for this purpose I'd say they're not the best idea. If you need this for nice display purposes, then CSV is probably the wrong format and HTML may be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert newline character (`n) between scopes:

```
[pscustomobject]@{Role='Role 01';Scope="Scope 01`nScope 02"},
[pscustomobject]@{Role='Role 02';Scope="Scope 01`nScope 03"} | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: Note: escape characters do not work in string literals (single-quotes `''`), only in expanded strings (double-quotes `""`).

Comment: I just updated the question with my sample. Thank you. The object is dynamically appended to the CSV so I'm unsure if using '`n` solves the problem

Comment: What is returned by `Get-Role`? (To simplify: what is the type of `$roleArray`?) Please run `$roleArray | gm`. It's declared as `object`.

Comment: @PawełDyl `$roleList` returns collection list.